# A word for someone who falsely believes that a danger is no threat

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I am looking for a succinct single word that sums up the following definition:

> A person who falsely believes that an impending danger is of no real threat

To add some context - I have frequently encountered climate change deniers online, but I have recently been encountering a whole new attitude.  People who agree that climate change is happening, but insist that it won't have any negative consequences or even go so far as to say that the world will be better off.

So the term "denier" doesn't fit.  "Liar" might be a better description, but I was looking specifically for a word that sums up the idea of falsely believing that a danger is, in fact, no danger at all.

Comment: I think denier still works here. They deny the possible dangerous consequences.

Comment: If you'd been asking this just before Jan 1st 2000, would you have applied the sought term to people who *didn't* believe civilisation would collapse because of Y2K computer bugs? Don't you just mean *person who doesn't believe every instance of media hype and scaremongering?* I'm also thinking of all those people who told Brits the world would end immediately if we voted to leave Europe (and told Americans the same would happen if they voted for Trump).

Comment: @FumbleFingers I am not going on media hype, I am going on the reports given out by every climatologist from every nation around the world.  They all agree that climate change is happening.  Regardless, it is up to you if you want to believe it is merely media hype - still, perhaps you could help with my initial question - looking for one word that sums up the idea of falsely believing that a danger is, in fact, no danger at all.

Comment: Whether the hype about global warming is true or not, the fact of the matter is you're really asking about how to characterise people who don't necessarily believe everything the media & politicians say, which isn't really the same thing as *refusing to accept "the truth"*. They might actually be ***open-minded***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers is it possible for you to ignore the context of this question, and simply provide me with a word that sums up the idea of "falsely believing that a danger is, in fact, no danger at all" ??

Comment: A word or phrase request can easily attract a long list of answers when it’s too subjective – more of a poll or request for ideas. Unfortunately neither are a good fit for the Stack Exchange model. A Stack Exchange question is objective and specific enough that it has a clearly “right” answer. See: “[Real questions have answers, not items or ideas or opinions](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/17/real-questions-have-answers/)”, “[Single word requests, crosswords, and the fight against mediocrity](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2160)”.

Comment: If possible, add more details of research you’ve done, especially solutions you’ve already rejected, and why. Include the desired connotation, register (formality), part of speech, and context in which it is to be used, and provide the exact enclosing sentence or passage. If this is not possible because you really do have a subjective question, a welcoming place to ask for advice is our [English Language & Usage Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95).

Comment: It seems to me your "context" implies ***wilfully and ignorantly*** refusing to recognise a clear and present danger, however that danger might be defined. That's to say you seem to be primarily looking for a pejorative insult to apply to people who don't agree with you, rather than someone who is unable to recognise risk factors.

Comment: @FumbleFingers so it seems you are incapable of ignoring the context and merely answering the question.  This is not about people who don't agree with me - this is about disagreements concerning climate change between two groups of people: one group who have done zero research on the subject and the other group have spent their lives studying the subject - I am merely siding with the group who has done the studying

Comment: If it's a matter of mistaken belief, I don't think _liar_ is at all suitable. A more appropriate term for this case would be something like **climate-change pollyanna**, meaning someone who feels that all will come out well on the climate-change front, without any changes in global policy or behavior, despite numerous indications to the contrary.

Comment: Interesting.  “confused”, “deluded” and “ignoramus” are a few of the many words that (arguably) fit, but are too general.  “ostrich with head stuck in sand” is, of course, a phrase; worse, it suggests that the subject is ignoring the threat, rather than acknowledging its existence and denying its danger/implications.

Comment: Of course, a climate-change skeptic or denier or pollyanna might assert as a contrary pejorative that a person who believes fervently in the catastrophic effects of climate change is a **climate-change chicken little**. That's how polemical characterizations like these go.

Comment: @SvenYargs I really like the term climate-change pollyanna :) I would suggest that the term for a person who believes fervently in the catastrophic effects of climate change is a climatologist, as this is what they are saying.

Answer (score 2):

You might try 
***[foolhardy](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/foolhardy)***.

Defined as:

> brave in a silly way, taking unnecessary risks

Answer (score 1):

The word I'd use is [**overconfident**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/overconfident). Or as a noun:

- > **Overconfidence** leads to bias in climate change estimations ([link](https://news.psu.edu/story/199344/2006/12/15/overconfidence-leads-bias-climate-change-estimations))